# How to reset the input value for the otp field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my codepen link https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/LYxOoWO

```html
<button @click="resetNow(id)"></button>
```

```js
resetNow(id){
    this.$refs[`input-${id}`].input.value = ""; //You may need to use .$el.value instead of .input.value
}
```

Tried resetting the value for the input OTP fields, but its not resetting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I'm not sure of why but it actually works with this code:

```js
resetNow() {
  this.activationKeyFields.forEach((_, index) => this.$refs[`input-${index}`][0].value = "")
},
```

So, by clicking on

```html
<button @click="resetNow">reset</button>
```

It is properly nullifying the content of all the fields.

Comment: i have added above code but, it's not resetting the value

Comment: Here is my codepen link  https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/LYxOoWO

Comment: You forgot the `id` >> `resetNow(id)`

Comment: Yes, it's working  But after passing the id, now it's resetting only the second  input value among 4 input fields.

Comment: But need to reset all 4 input otp fields

Comment: It's perfectly working fine, Thanks for your time. :)